# Application not loading on host port - Docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container, docker-image

**Docker service is unable to load on exposed port**

I have created a simple `DOCKERFILE` and have built image "sample-image" from it inside a docker swarm, but whenever I am trying to run a container by creating docker service and exposing it on respective port but its unable to load on my browser. Kindly help

First I have initialised docker swarm and created an image "sample-image" from dockerfile, after that I created overlay network "sample-network" inside swarm and created a service to run container on it `"docker service create --name sample-service -p 8010:8001 --network sample-network sample-image"`. Service gets created but it couldn't loads up on a browser as I have enabled my ufw for port `8010` also.

***DOCKERFILE:***

```
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8001
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

***server.js:***

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const PORT = 8001;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

**I expect my web browser to display "Hello world" on exposed port number.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the docker logs ? That should give you what is going wrong.

```
$ docker logs <containerid>
```

Comment: yes! I already checked logs and it is fine I guess. please see below what docker log shows: > docker_web_app@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js

Running on http://0.0.0.0:8001

Comment: try change host , try docker internal default gateway usually is 172.17.0.1 , but you can inspect network , docker inspect network brige  , and then check the value for your gateway ..

Comment: oh okay.. then please try getting into your container and see whether the app works..

docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash

curl -i localhost:8010

Comment: @JoaquinJavi After inspecting the network the value of gateway appears to be "Gateway": "10.0.0.1" so is it possible we can modify gateway to get appropriate result.

Comment: @NabeelShaikh no i mean change the host const to docker gateway

Comment: @JoaquinJavi that trick worked used default gateway 172.17.0.1 and that's all was required. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try "curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8081" and paste the output here please? Also, did you manipulate ufw after the service or dockerd started?

Comment: curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8081
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:8081/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8081: Connection refused

Comment: Hey this is the real problem I guess, when I check exposed port 8001 it also says   "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8001: Connection refused" can you please help me out to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8010". Could you also do a docker service ls, just to be sure the port is actually open.

Comment: thank you Frank for your correct suggestions, as I have already resolved it, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your listening port inside docker is 8010, and outside docker is 8001, can you try changing `-p 8001:8001`? if it works try `-p 8001:8010`.

Comment: Port1 is where the service is exposed to outer network and Port2 is the port on which service runs. I have checked by making these changes still it wont works.